# UIDatePicker for a Non-Gregorian calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar, uidatepicker

I am using UIDatePicker in my App, which works fine for a Gregorian calendar.
But I want to use a Non-Gregorian calendar with the DatePicker, which I didn't succeed to do it!
I need it to do some conversion from Non-Gregorian to Gregorian dates, so it must work the same whatever the iPhone 'Locales' are.

Please can you answer this!

Your help is really appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the `UIDatePicker`'s `calendar` property to a non-Gregorian calendar?

Comment: Thanks Dave.

Yes I set the calendar property to a non-Gregorian calendar in viewDidLoad as an example:
NSCalendar *myCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSChineseCalendar];
pickerView.calendar = myCal;

But this keeps the Gregorian calendar, shifted by few weeks (for today it just display the DatePicker with Gregorian date; with August 6, 2010 as default date).

Comment: Did you happen to fix this @Jason? I'm having the same problem and still can't figure it out.

Comment: @iMohammad setting the calendar should work as of iOS 6.  It was unreliable in previous versions.

Comment: Testing on iOS6 simulator is working perfectly fine as you said. However, i'm testing on a 5.1.1 iPhone 4 and it's not working fine as @Jason said. I want my app to be able to work for at least iOS5 and above. So, I hope he found a fix.