# Converting NSDate from a calendar to another

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker, nscalendar

I'm having trouble here. Took me hours but no use. Please keep in mind I checked the heck of StackOverFlow for a fix but there isn't any.

When I convert the `_date` Object from `Gregorian` to `Hijri` it does not convert. I know that because when I print it it still gives me the `Gregorian` day. This troubles me because I want to `setDate` of a `UIDatePicker` and it's setting it incorrectly because the `_date` is `gregorian` and my `UIDatePicker` object calendar set to `setCalendar:_hijriCalendar`

```
//DATE SETTING
_date = [NSDate date];
_hijriCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];
_gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *currentDateComponents = [_hijriCalendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];


NSDate *islamicDate =[_hijriCalendar dateFromComponents:currentDateComponents];

NSLog(@" Current Date: %@",islamicDate);  //this outputs gregorian current date not Hijri
```

NOTE: Guys, I don't want just print the date. I know using a `NSDateFotmatter` set to the correct `NSCalendar` object will do the job. But I want to convert the date to a new date to set it to my `UIDatePicker`. I hope you guys get what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `NSDate` object represents a moment in time, *irrespective* of any calendar, time zone, or relativity (this last one is generally considered to be a non-issue in Earth-based computer science.)

When you create an instance of `NSDate` through any means, it is stored as simply the number of seconds since a fixed point in time (12:00 AM GMT on January 1, 2001 in the case of iOS and OS X.)

As a result, converting a date from Gregorian to Hijri doesn't *do* anything because that fixed moment remains the same.

If you tell us specifically what transformation you expect to occur between Gregorian and Hijri that is not already occurring, we can suggest an alternate course of action.

Comment: What an excellent explanation! My problem mainly in `UIDatePicker`. Today's date in Hijri is 15 Dul-Hijja 1433. But when I open the app `UIDatePicker` is not set to the default current date. It is set to 27 Dul-Qidah 1433 which is month before. Although `UIDatePicker` is `setDate:[NSDate date];` In Simulator it just works fine! because iOS6 and Apple fixed all these bugs. But on my device iOS5 is a troublesome.

Comment: As a new version of the OS solves the problem, it is strongly implied that this is a bug Apple found and fixed independently. If that's the case, you should consider requiring iOS 6. If you must support iOS 5, be warned that attempting to map the differences in the dates is fraught with peril, because there is no guarantee that the difference is constant over time.

Comment: Yeah but many apps their datepicker is working fine on ios5 . I have a problem and I dont know whats a fix for it. Let me give you this link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3704750/652021 read Json comment. He had the exact issue. Im sure there is a way to fix this. Because all apps are showing uidatepicker just fine for non-gregorian calendars on old ios versions.

Comment: As per the comments on that question, it appears to have been fixed in iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make any conversions at all.

`NSLog` prints object's `description` method. Since `NSDate` stores only amount of seconds since reference date and does not keep a track of calendar it belongs to, it uses Gregorian calendar to format date for `description` method.

Customize `NSDateFormatter` to use your calendar and use `stringFromDate:` to get localized string value for your date.

Comment: This is the thing, I don't want to just print. I used printing to check why my`UIDatePicker` is not set to the correct `Hijri` date. I know setting  `NSDateFormatter` to `HijriCalendar` will print the correct date. But I want to use the `_date` object to set my `UIDatePicker`

Comment: Guess you meant to use `_gregCalendar` intead of `_hijriCalendar` when getting `currentDateComponents`. In other way this will produce same `NSDate` value. Right?

Comment: If I use `_gregCalendar` instead of `_HijriCalendar` I get the value `2574-06-20` and my UIDatePicker ruin dates more. I just need to get the correct date in `_HijriCalendar` to set it to my UIDatePicker and solve this problem "sigh".